# Making UIPickerview on top of another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS programming and having trouble with setting `UIPickerView`.
What I am trying to do is showing the `UIPickerView` on top of another view when one of the button in the main view is clicked. I am doing all this in the storyboard but cannot manage two views on the same position. So what I am thinking is set one of the view in storyboard and making this other programmatically. Or I have heard of `UIContainerView` to manage two controller views on the same position. Which one is the better way to do this? Or is there another better way? Included a picture.
[image]

Comment: you can manage the views set in storyboard too. Please provide more info. WHat you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri isn't this clear enough?? Do you mean source code? There is not really much source code involved since I tried all of this in storyboard. I having trouble managing two views on the same position since one view overlap the other one.

Comment: go with input view, it will make it show up from the bottom, google this "setinputview uipickerview"

Comment: Any number of views can be placed at same position on single viewcontroller using any way, storyboard or programmatically.

Comment: @gunjotsingh The thing is how? I have been trying to find the solution but could not find any. Hiding another view while working on the other view will be enough for me if there isn't any better solution.